# AngularJS 2 what is http-server and how http-server works internally

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, httpserver

Currently I am refering two project to understand the angularjs 2 project.

```
https://plnkr.co/edit/rxtAgu3PqoNkV90vBSEX?p=preview
https://plnkr.co/edit/KpDLgX9fym27XVPwaERo?p=preview
```

I have downloaded these two project and try to run on my computer. After putting lot of effort I am able to run by using

```
    http-server -p 4545 command.
```

I Have following Questions..

1) How npm http-server works internally (It means which file it will read to start the server)

2) If I want to compile this project. How can i compile these project.Currently I am not able to compile these project to see the changes

3) If i am directly putting path(filepath) of index.html on browser why it is not running(becuase finally it is javascript.) And Is plunker is using http-server inside their code

4) Is http-server inside the npm package?

Comment: did you read node documentation?

Comment: I have read documentation... But if i get help of this particular project then it will be better for me.